# Populating parent Reference (List) in CloudKit with child recordName when creating a child record

Tags: swift, cloudkit

I'm trying to build additional functionality beyond that included in a cloudkit tutorial (https://www.raywenderlich.com/4878052-cloudkit-tutorial-getting-started) and have gotten to the point where I have a working app to view Establishments (restaurants) and Notes about them - where I've created the data in the CloudKit dashboard and pre-populated the Notes' recordName(s) in the Establishment's 'notes' Reference (List).

I'm now extending the app to allow the user to add notes and at a point where I'm able to create a new Note, and populate the Establishment's recordName (establishing the parent entity within the child record) with this:

```
let noteRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "Note")
noteRecord["text"] = noteText.text //grabbed from a UIAlert

if self.establishment?.name != nil { //If the establishment exists
  let reference = CKRecord.Reference(recordID: self.establishment!.id, action: .deleteSelf)
  noteRecord["establishment"] = reference as! CKRecordValue
}
   //works fine, saves the new note as expected with the right recordName for the establishment
CKContainer.default().privateCloudDatabase.save(noteRecord) { [unowned self] record, error in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let error = error {
        } else {
        }
    }
}
```

Now the issue I have is how to grab the recordName of this newly saved Note and append it to the Reference (list) of the Establishment.

The reason being that the way the app was built in the tutorial - when getting all the Notes for an Establishment - it uses the Reference (List) of the establishment.  If folks think this is unnecessary from a data structure and just having the reference back to the parent on the child is enough, I'd be interested in the pros/cons of the approaches.  As you can tell, I'm just learning!

Any ideas?  Thank you!!

Please let me know if more detail would be useful

[Data model for Notes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQy1a.png) - what matters is: "text" = String of the note and "establishment" = reference that holds the Establishment recordName
[Data model for Establishment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h86GV.png) - what matters is "notes" which is a Reference (List) of recordNames of Note items.

GitHub repository here as well: https://github.com/SteveBlackUK/BabiFudTutorial/blob/master/BabiFud/View%20Controllers/NotesTableViewController.swift < this is the view controller I'm working on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I still have an open question about whether you should store the parent child references in both the parent and the child (probably)...I was finally able to figure out how to append the reference to the child back in the parent record.

Reminder: we are creating a Note about a location (an Establishment), and the goal is to store the reference to the note in the Reference (list) within the Establishment in CloudKit.

```
//first, make sure we even have an establishment
  if self.establishment?.name != nil {
        //get the array of note references for the Establishment that we want to update
        let noteReferences = CKRecord.Reference(record: noteRecord, action: CKRecord_Reference_Action.deleteSelf)
//store the current array of note references into notesForEstablishment
        self.notesForEstablishment = self.establishment?.noteRecords
        if self.notesForEstablishment != nil {
          if !self.notesForEstablishment!.contains(noteReferences) {
            self.notesForEstablishment!.append(noteReferences)
          }
        } else {
          self.notesForEstablishment = [noteReferences]
          self.establishment?.noteRecords = self.notesForEstablishment
        }

        // get the record ID for the current establishment
        let establishmentRecordID = self.establishment?.id
        //then fetch the establishment from CK
        CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase.fetch(withRecordID: establishmentRecordID!) { updatedRecord, error in
          if let error = error {
            print("error handling to come: \(error.localizedDescription)")
          } else {
// then update the record and place the array that now holds the reference to the new note into the "notes" Reference (list) in CK
            updatedRecord!.setObject(self.notesForEstablishment as __CKRecordObjCValue?, forKey: "notes")
            CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase.save(updatedRecord!) { savedRecord, error in

            }
          }
        }
      }
```

It could probably be much cleaner code - and any feedback welcome, but it works!